# Getting items object and their totalCost from an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java

Please I need help.

I am trying to finish 2 different java methods.

1- the first method is  called getOrder() which is supposed to get an order of different items that have already been added to an ArrayList named order but I just did not include the code for it as I think it is not necessary. I need to return all the contents of order ArrayList as long as it does not contain null.
The getItem method (which is working perfectly) Loads the contents of the items in the order using the class A4Q1Util.

The problem that I have is with this line of code:

```
return toBeReturned.add(A4Q1Util.getItem());
```

it gives the following error:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to java.util.ArrayList

2- In the second method (printOrderCos), I am supossed to print out the totalCost of items from the ArrayList order. I defined the variable totalCost and count. Count is defined so that it works as an index that goes through each element(item) of the order ArrayList and then adds up the cost of each item to totalCost.

The problem that I encounter with the second method is with this line of code:

```
totalCost+=order.get(count);
```

it gives an error:

error: The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Item

```
public static ArrayList<Item> getOrder()
     {

          ArrayList<Item> toBeReturned;
          toBeReturned = new ArrayList<Item>();

          while (A4Q1Util.getItem()!=null)
          {
          return toBeReturned.add(A4Q1Util.getItem());
          }

     }


     public static void printOrderCost(ArrayList<Item> order)//prints the total cost of the    order
     {
          double totalCost;
          int count;
          totalCost=0;

          for (count=0;count<order.size();count++)
          {
          totalCost+=order.get(count);//intValue();
          }
          System.out.println("The total cost of your order is:");
     }


 class Item
{
  protected String description;
  protected int quantity;

 public Item (String description, int quantity)
 {
   this.description = description;
   this.quantity = quantity;
 }

 } 

 class Coffee extends Item
{
  protected double unitCost;
  public Coffee (String description, int quantity)
 {
   super(description, quantity);//cost?,and price extraction
   unitCost=4;
 }


}

 class Muffin extends Item
{
  protected double unitCost1, unitCost2, unitCost3;
  public Muffin (String description, int quantity)
 {
   super(description,quantity);
   unitCost1=1;
   unitCost2=0.75;
   unitCost3=0.50;
 }


}


 class TimBits extends Item
{
 protected double unitCost;
 public TimBits (String description, int quantity)
 {
   super(description, quantity);
   unitCost=0.25;
 }
}
class A4Q1Util
{
 private static ArrayList<Item> order;

 private static int count = 0;

 public static Item getItem()
 {
  Item item;

  if (order==null)
  {
   order = new ArrayList<Item>();

   order.add(new Muffin("Bran", 3));
   order.add(new Coffee("Latte", 1));
   order.add(new TimBits("Assorted", 24));
   order.add(new Muffin("Chocolate", 1));
   order.add(new Coffee("Decaf", 2));
   order.add(new TimBits("Chocolate", 12));
   order.add(new Muffin("PeanutButter", 2));
   order.add(new Muffin("Blueberry", 5));
  }

  item = null;
  if (count<order.size())
  {
   item = order.get(count);
   count++;
  }
  {
  return item;
  }



}
}
```

Comment: If your question is answered, accept the appropriate answer, do not remove your quesiton from the site!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you *exactly* what is wrong:

You're trying to add an Item to a number, which obviously is not going to work. Instead perhaps you want to call a method on the item returned from the list, perhaps a `getCost()` method or something similar. We don't have the Item class code to look at, and so cannot tell you which method to call, but hopefully your Item class has an appropriate method which returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `get()` seems that is returning an `Item` instance, so you may want to create a method (if it's not already created) to return a number that you can use to add to `totalCost`, maybe something like:

```
totalCost += order.get(count).getCost(...); // getCost(...) is the method you should create
```

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd problem , problem is "order.get(count)" returns Item object . and You cannot added "Item object" with double.

Comment: can you share your Item class? Then I will be to tell exact solution to it

Comment: Create on method getCost() with return type Double  in the Item class, which should return the cost of the Item

Comment: Ok, seeThec, I did share item class with all it's subclasses. Thanks in advance

Comment: please help me fixing problem 2

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1 :

```
public static ArrayList<Item> getOrder()
     {

          ArrayList<Item> toBeReturned;
          toBeReturned = new ArrayList<Item>();
          Item item;
          item=A4Q1Util.getItem();
          while (item!=null)
          {
           toBeReturned.add(item);// it will all the items from A4Q1Util class to list
           item=A4Q1Util.getItem();   
          }
        return toBeReturned;

     }
```